# OpenCV header file error in omnet++

Tags: opencv, omnet++, build-error

I'm trying to build a project in omnet++ (the project uses OpenCV). My problem I believe is related to the linking between the project and the libraries.

The compiler throws these 2 erros :

```
fatal error: cxcore.h: No such file or directory  WiseGuiWorldOpencv.h /M3WSN/src/gui/opencv line 18 C/C++ Problem
make: *** [out/gcc-debug//src/gui/opencv/WiseGuiWorldOpencv.o]
```

how  can I fix it ?

Comment: cxcore is from the outdated c-api, which was discarded 5 years ago. expect trouble (the libs won't exist anymore, either). consider looking for an alternative, better maintained project.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an older version of OpenCV 2.4.2 as that is one used in the M3WSN framework.I have installed successfully using the following configuration:

1. Ubuntu 14.4
2. Omnet++ 4.1
3. OpenCV 2.4.2 http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/opencv/OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2/059ef86fc1724d69b75832a0d2929ff5/